# Python regex match grouping

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

RANDOMSTRING are alphanumeric including spaces at most 50 characters

```
RANDOMSTRING $RANDOMFLOAT Paid with Visa ending in RANDOMINT *- For: RANDOMSTRING -*

RANDOMINTx *RANDOMSTRING* (RANDOMSTRING)
=E2=80=A2 RANDOMSTRING1

$RANDOMFLOAT
RANDOMINTx RANDOMSTRING (RANDOMSTRING)
=E2=80=A2 RANDOMSTRING2
=E2=80=A2 RANDOMSTRING3
=E2=80=A2 RANDOMSTRING4
=E2=80=A2 RANDOMSTRING5

$RANDOMFLOAT
RANDOMINTx *RANDOMSTRING* (RANDOMSTRING)
=E2=80=A2 RANDOMSTRING6
=E2=80=A2 RANDOMSTRING7

$RANDOMFLOAT
RANDOMINTx *RANDOMSTRING* (RANDOMSTRING)
=E2=80=A2 RANDOMSTRING8
=E2=80=A2 RANDOMSTRING9
```

Hello I want to get the `RANDOMSTRING`s in each of the `=E2=80=A2` lines as an array of arrays. They are grouped according to the =E2=80=A2 grouping.

Example expected output:

```
[[RANDOMSTRING1], [RANDOMSTRING2, RANDOMSTRING3, RANDOMSTRING4, RANDOMSTRING5], [RANDOMSTRING6, RANDOMSTRING7], [RANDOMSTRING8, RANDOMSTRING9]]
```

What I use:

```
menu_item_accessories_items = re.findall("((=E2=80=A2 .*$)|\n\n)", bodytext, re.MULTILINE)
```

Output I get (array of touples):

```
[(RANDOMSTRING1, RANDOMSTRING1), (RANDOMSTRING2, RANDOMSTRING2), (RANDOMSTRING3, RANDOMSTRING3), (RANDOMSTRING4, RANDOMSTRING4), (RANDOMSTRING5, RANDOMSTRING5), (RANDOMSTRING6, RANDOMSTRING6), (RANDOMSTRING7, RANDOMSTRING7), (RANDOMSTRING8, RANDOMSTRING8), (RANDOMSTRING9, RANDOMSTRING9)]
```

Comment: What characters can a `RANDOMSTRING` contain? Or do they literally say "RANDOMSTRING"?

Comment: RANDOMSTRING are alphanumeric including spaces at most 50 characters

Comment: Can adapt something like:`[[el.partition(' ')[2] for el in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(bodytext.splitlines(), lambda L: L.startswith('=E2=80=A2')) if k]` ? It's a bit hard to be specific as it's not the most readable of an example :)

Comment: @JonClements Thanks so much man

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the most elegant method, and I'm not sure how it would handle corner cases not presented here, but the code below first builds a single list delimited by empty lines.  It then iterates over all entries, creating a new list each time it encounters a delimiter.

```
lines = [x for x in bodytext.split('\n') if x == '' or x.startswith('=E2=80=A2')]

res = []
tmp = []
for line in lines:
    if line == '':
        if len(tmp) > 0:
            res += [tmp]
        tmp = []
    else:
        tmp += line.split(' ')[1:]

print res
```